# Trying to deploy Presto and the page wont load when i try to access the console

Tags: java, presto

I followed the steps exactly from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAkLG3g0FOU

When I run
`user@DESKTOP-8H20KA2:~/presto-server-0.238.2$ bin/launcher start ERROR: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/presto'`
I get permission denied, so i run it as sudo.

When i run it as sudo i get: `user@DESKTOP-8H20KA2:~/presto-server-0.238.2$ sudo bin/launcher start Started as 2628`

I then try to load the page at 127.0.0.1:8090 and I get "This page isnt working"

When running `sudo bin/launcher start --verbose` I see the message
`['java', '-cp', '/home/user/presto-server-0.238.2/lib/*', '-server', '-Xmx16G', '-XX:+UseG1GC', '-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M', '-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit', '-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent', '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError', '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p', '-Dnode.environment=production', '-Dnode.id=f7c4bf3c-dbb4-4807-baae-9b7e41807bc8', '-Dnode.data-dir=/var/presto/data', '-Dlog.levels-file=/home/user/presto-server-0.238.2/etc/log.properties', '-Dlog.output-file=/var/presto/data/var/log/server.log', '-Dlog.enable-console=false', '-Dconfig=/home/user/presto-server-0.238.2/etc/config.properties', 'com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer']`

I know that there is a Java requirement, so when i run
`user@DESKTOP-8H20KA2:~/presto-server-0.238.2$ java -version openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)`

I can confirm i have java, but does it HAVE to be version 8? Or is 8 or higher still good?  If so, how do i go about switching to Java 8? Or could i be running into other issues?

Answer (score 1):

Presto version supporting and requiring Java 11 is hosted at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/ . Please check out the code from there.
Since the video is 2 years old, it may be outdated. You can always get help on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).